# using present tense for shot period events

Tags: present-tense

**The child goes to bed.

He takes a chair.

He wants to know your name.**

are these sentences are valid for present tense.
 can I use present simple for short period events.

Comment: This seems to be proofreading. Edit your post to show which description the sentences belong.

Comment: The first two sound like action directions as in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native speaker, I feel that only one of the three sentences is a statement about the present moment:

> He wants to know your name.

The other two statements have a narrative quality or the quality of a general fact.  If we wanted to say that those things are happening now, at this moment, we would say

The child is going to bed.

He is taking a chair.